# Java mouseClicked complication

Tags: java, mouselistener

*Code works, my bad. But I'm still open to suggestions on how to improve or make the code more elegant.*

I have created this layout and I want to be able to draw a circle whenever the user clicks on the white area.

[Couldn't post an image, so here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5N0I.jpg)

The white area is basically a rectangle. But something with my code isn't working, it just doesn't respond to mouse clicks. When I tried to see if it responds to mouseDragged it worked perfectly but this isn't what I need.

Here is my code, some "tests" are put as /*comments*/ but neither of them work as intended. 
I would be very grateful for help. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

```
public class CitiesMapPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

private JButton cmdAddWay, cmdFindPath, cmdClearMap, cmdClearPath;
private JLabel lblFrom, lblTo;
private JTextField txtFrom, txtTo;

public CitiesMapPanel() {

    cmdAddWay = new JButton("Add Way");
    cmdFindPath = new JButton("Find Path");
    cmdClearMap = new JButton("Clear Map");
    cmdClearPath = new JButton("Clear Path");
    lblFrom = new JLabel("From");
    lblTo = new JLabel("To");
    txtFrom = new JTextField(6);
    txtTo = new JTextField(6);

    this.addMouseListener(this);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());      
    add(buildGui(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}




private JPanel buildGui() {
    JPanel buttonsBar = new JPanel();
    //The "south" of the BorderLayout consist of a (2,4) GridLayout.

    buttonsBar.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));
    buttonsBar.add(lblFrom);
    buttonsBar. add(txtFrom);
    buttonsBar.add(lblTo);
    buttonsBar.add(txtTo);
    buttonsBar.add(cmdAddWay);
    buttonsBar.add(cmdFindPath);
    buttonsBar.add(cmdClearMap);
    buttonsBar.add(cmdClearPath);
    return buttonsBar;
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().height, this.getSize().width);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("layout");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(530, 550);
    CitiesMapPanel gui = new CitiesMapPanel();
    frame.add(gui);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/*abstract private class MyMouseListner implements MouseListener{
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(x,y,15,15);          
    }
}*/

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(x,y,15,15);   
    System.out.println("test");

}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: That's weird, because when I click the white area it draws a small black circle and the word "test" is written to standard output.

Comment: It responds on my computer.

Comment: Wow it actually does! Because of frustration I just didn't notice that because it's not the smoothest.
I feel so embarrassed now!
Anyway is this how it's supposed to be done or is there a more elegant way of doing it? Apart from overriding all the methods (and I can't set the class to abstract)

Answer (score 1):

The click listener is not the problem. Your approach to painting is simply wrong. You can't do a `getGraphic`, paint on it, and expect the result to be presented. In Swing (AWT) things work fundamentally different. You need to either create an off screen image that you paint to and that you then present on screen in your `paintComponent` method, or you need to track the objects you want to paint in a data structure and paint those in your `paintComponent` method. You can trigger a repaint in your click listener by calling `repaint` so the UI subsystems knows about the changed state that requires a repaint of your component.

Read more about the basics in the [Swing painting tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: Luck. Plus "it is not the smoothest" doesn't sound like we have 2014. And I guess there are things not even tested yet, like different OS or resizing the frame.